# matrix transpose function not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, transpose

I have a matrix which i want to transpose and I've done this before and it's worked, but it's only today while I've been going through my code and updating it that it has suddenly stopped working. I really don't know why, as it has worked fine before. Here's the main bit of code

```py
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.matrix = [[0]*self.rows]]*self.cols

    def transpose(self):
        transposed_matrix = Matrix(self.rows, self.cols)

        for i in range(self.cols):
            for j in range(self.rows):
                transposed_matrix.matrix[j][i] = self.matrix[i][j]

        return transposed_matrix
```

So say I have a matrix like this

```
[
     [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
     [1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
     [-1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0]
     [-1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0]
]
```

I'm expecting

```
[
    [0, 1, -1, -1]
    [1, -1, -1, 1]
    [1, 0, 0, -1, -1]
    [0, 0, -1, -1]
    [0, 0, 1, -1]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
]
```

But instead I'm getting

```
[
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
    [0, -1, 0, 0]
]
```

If you can help shed some light on this then that would be really appreciated

Comment: change `[[0]*self.rows]]*self.cols` into `[[0]*self.rows] for i in range(self.cols)]` and google "How does Python referencing work"

Comment: `transposed-matrix` is not a valid variable name, you can't use `-` in variables as it is the subtraction operator. Please do test the code you post in questions.

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi Thank you, it's now fixed. Although i don't understand how that made a difference. Could you please explain it

Comment: See the duplicate; multiplication doesn't create copies of contained objects; all you get is repeated references. A list comprehension on the other hand executes the expression at the start each iteration, creating a new list object each time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry i didn't realize i thought i put a "_" not a "-"